# Convert Bytes to int 0x Python

Tags: python

```
file = open('calc.exe', 'rb')
file.seek(0x3c)
data = file.read(4)
file.seek(data)
```

data return bytes in this form: b'\xe8\x00\x00\x00'
seek needs int in this form 0xe8
how can I do it?

Comment: `file.seek(int(bytes(reversed(data)).hex(), 16))` if needed little endian or `file.seek(int(data.hex(), 16))` if needed big endian.

Comment: As it appeared to be there is even simpler one built-in function `int.from_bytes(data, 'little')` or `int.from_bytes(data, 'big')` for little and big endian. But this functions appeared only from Python 3.2. But `.hex()` mentioned above also appeared in quite recent Pythons.